# .htaccess Leverage browser caching not working

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I have following code in .htaccess file and it is not working for me :

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType images/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType images/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType images/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>


<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: is mod_expires enabled and active?

Comment: also, your deflate block is wrong, should be `IfModule` not `ifModule`